# File Upload Validation asp

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, regex, file-upload

I try to validate `FileUpload` control to check the extension of files by this regular expression

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator5" ValidationGroup="PersonalGroup" 
           ControlToValidate="FileUpload1" Runat="Server"
            ErrorMessage="Only .pdf & .doc files are allowed" ValidationExpression="[^\.]\.pdf\.docx\.doc$" />*</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

my problem to check the FileUpload already has file or not before i click the button submit because i got `NullReferenceException` if don't have file i try to make this

```
if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
                {
                    book.Book_File = System.IO.Path.GetPathRoot(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
                }
```

but the problem still exist if the user didn't uploaded any file.
How to check the `FileUpload` is required filed before submit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `RequiredFieldValidator`. Its available in the controls list.

Something like :

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvFileupload" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Image is Required !" ControlToValidate="yourFileUploadID"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Comment: I try to use it but the problem still exist because this Validator check after i click submit button

Comment: Did you provide validation group using this validator ? Because you have used in your `RegularExpressionValidator` so use it in this one too and try.

Comment: Glad that it helped you through !

Answer (score 0):

You could also use below condition check behind your button:

```
If (page.isValid) {
//here goes your code behind button
}
```